# How to convert a binary heap to binomial queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, heap

Given a binary heap, How can I convert it to a binomial queue in linear time- O(n)? I thought of splitting the heap however I got stuck as the time for deletion is O(lg n)

Comment: What exactly got you stuck? O(lg n) is less than O(n) so deleting shouldn't be a problem. But also your main approach should just be moving around subtrees, which doesn't require deletion...

Comment: Couldn't solve it, like I thought of removing the right most subtrees and merging them into bigger queue then merge them. But couldn't rap my min around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to the backing array that contains the binary heap and you can iterate over it in O(n) time, then you can create your binomial heap simply by doing n inserts. As the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) says:

> Inserting a new element to a heap can be done by simply creating a new
>   heap containing only this element and then merging it with the
>   original heap. Due to the merge, insert takes O(log n) time. However,
>   across a series of n consecutive insertions, insert has an amortized
>   time of O(1) (i.e. constant).

In other words, doing n inserts into the binomial heap will require O(n) time.

You cannot do this in O(n) time by using the standard binary heap remove operation. As you noted, that would be O(log n) for each removal, resulting in O(n log n) complexity.